# Tokenizing a file

Tags: python

In my CS class I have been given a task to read in the entire corpus of Shakespeare's Plays and Sonnets and print out the number of times a particular word occurs. Can anyone help me get my feet off the ground with this. Here is the first level of the stepwise refinement I was given.

Level 0
Define a function that tokenizes a file, returning an array of tokens. Loop through the array, printing each token one per line. For example, your specialized main might look something like this:

```
def main():
    tokens = readTokens("shakespeare.txt")
    for i in range(0,len(tokens),1):
        print(tokens[i])
```

I guess my real question is how do I tokenize a file and then read it into an array into python? Sorry if this kind of question is not what this website is for, Im just looking for some help. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Give some things you've tried and what hasn't worked/has worked partially, you'll be more likely to get help.

Comment: How do you define “tokens” in your case?

Answer (score 2):

```
goodletters = set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' \t")

def tokenize_file(fname):
    tokens = []
    with open(fname) as inf:
        for line in inf:
            clean = ''.join(ch for ch in line.lower() if ch in goodletters)
            tokens.extend(clean.split())
    return tokens
```

Written this way for clarity; in production, I would use `inf.read().translate()`, but the setup for that is significantly different for Python 2.x vs 3.x and I'd prefer not to be more confusing than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

def readTokens(file):
    tokens = Counter()
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            tokens += Counter(word.strip() for word in line.split())
            # if you're trying to count "Won't", "won't", and "won't!"
            # all together, do this instead:
            ## tokens += Counter(word.strip('"!?,.;:').casefold() for word in line.split())
    return tokens

def main():
    tokens = readTokens('shakespeare.txt')
    for token in tokens:
        print(token)
    print("The most commonly used word is {}".format(max(tokens.items(), key=
                                                    lambda x: x[1])))
```

Comment: Use of Counter is good, however this will count ie "won't", "Won't," and "won't." as separate words (it does not strip punctuation or normalize capitalization).

Comment: @HughBothwell Without more info from OP, it's hard to say whether or not he wants that. I implemented the bare bones, but without further input I'm loathe to strip input text.

Comment: @HughBothwell That said, I think your `goodletters` implementation is great! I considered stealing it ;). Maybe we should combine our answers?

Comment: no problem; as you say, he may be happy with that. If you want to borrow, go ahead, but why not show the usage of str.translate instead?

Comment: I don't know if I would use `str.translate` in this case, since I'm mapping LOTS OF STUFF to `None` and only really using `str.casefold()` on the rest. I would do it your way ;)

Comment: (blink) this is the first time I've heard of `str.casefold()` - it doesn't seem to be any different from `str.lower()` except that it isn't available in Python 2.x! The main difference is speed - translate is compiled C code, and should be considerably faster (at the cost of more work setting it up).

Comment: @HughBothwell it's no different in English. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold), "Casefolding is similar to lowercasing but more aggressive because it is intended to remove all case distinctions in a string. For example, the German lowercase letter `'ß'` is equivalent to `"ss"`. Since it is already lowercase, lower() would do nothing to `'ß'`; casefold() converts it to `"ss"`."

Comment: @HughBothwell how would you do the `str.translate`? I built it quickly as `trans = str.maketrans("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",'"!?,.:;')`, `new_string = old_string.translate(trans)`? I've never used it in Python2, so I'm lost there (iirc you have to pass it a dict like `{"A":"a", ",":''}` etc?)